# UITextField Value Changed Event?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

How can I make it so that when the contents of a text field changes, a function is called?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**Objective-C**

```
[myTextField addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

**Swift 4**

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {...}
```

Comment: Weird, based on UIControlEventDidEnd & UIControlEventDidBegin, one would assume that it was UIControlEventValueChanged... What exactly does UIControlEventValueChanged do then?

Comment: @kovpas if we change value programmatically then it didn't get call, any idea what to do ?. for example myTextField.text = "Krishna"

Answer (score 26):

Actually, there is no value changed event for `UITextField`, use `UIControlEventEditingChanged`

Answer (score 8):

I resolved the issue changing the behavior of shouldChangeChractersInRange. If you return NO the changes won't be applied by iOS internally, instead you have the opportunity to change it manually and perform any actions after the changes.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    //Replace the string manually in the textbox
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    //perform any logic here now that you are sure the textbox text has changed
    [self didChangeTextInTextField:textField];
    return NO; //this make iOS not to perform any action
}
```

Comment: Note that setting text property will move cursor to the end of text, which might affect editing

Comment: You can handle it by yourself

Answer (score 3):

this is my solution.

**Swift 4**

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField){
   print("textFieldDidChange is called")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For swift this comes handy -

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTextChange), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```